# Does Valve still support The Orange Box TF2 on the Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, team-fortress-2

Is Valve still supporting (i.e. occasionally releasing updates for) Team Fortress 2 on the Xbox 360?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last update for Xbox 360 was [back in 2009](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Patches#Xbox_360_patches).  I wouldn't expect any further patches for the Xbox 360 at this point.